# Doing operations between an int and double

Tags: c, math, int, double, operand

I have a homework assignment in basic C that is asking me to calculate certain expressions and then check my answers in a program. I can't seem to get any of these answers correct by my own calculations...

They want me to solve math problems using these variables:

```
int a = 2;
double b = 4.7;
int c = 3;
double d = 4.2;
```

Here's an example question:

```
int answer1 = b+a/c-d;
```

I understand that since it has an int operand then all the variables convert to an integer, so it should look something like this I think:

(4+2)/(3-4)

I got -6 as my answer when doing it by hand, but when I input it as code it gives me an answer of 0. Can anyone explain this? Am I doing the order of operations wrong? I simply don't understand how the computer gets 0 out of that. This is the easiest question in my homework and I don't have a clue. Please help!

Comment: Firstly, "I understand that since it has an int operand then all the variables convert to an integer" - that is already not even remotely true. Secondly, you C expression `b+a/c-d` has no braces in it. Your mathematical expression `(4+2)/(3-4)` has braces in it. Why the difference?

Comment: Okay, I feel stupid now. So is the final answer the only thing that gets converted to a integer? Looks like I should have taken a math class beforehand for review haha. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression

```
b+a/c-d
```

is the same as

```
b + (a/c) - d
```

Since both `a` and `c` are integers, then the quotient `a/c` is computed using integer division. That gives `2/3 = 0`. So then you have:

```
b - d
```

This is calculated using floating point since `b` and `d` are `double`. The result is 0.5, which when assigned to the result `int`, is truncated to 0.

Comment: Ahhhh! Now I see where I went wrong. I guess I needed some review in basic order of operations. Thank you for providing clarity!

Answer (score 1):

Your orders of operations is a bit off:

```
int answer1 = b+(a/c)-d; 

int tmp1 = a/c; ---> 2/3 --> 0
int answer1 = 4.7 + 0 - 4.2 ----> 0.5 --> 0
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/